# how to make array include a PDF document

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, if-statement

I am new to swift and trying to figure out how to code my array to include a PDF document. I set up a tableView as when a cell is clicked will move to a new detail view controller.  I want the new detail controller to display the PDF associated with the cell that was selected. Is there an intelligent way to code this?

I have been struggling with how to code this portion.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class State
{
    var title: String
    var detailText: String
    var description: String
    var image: UIImage

    var document: PDFDocument

    init(titled: String, detailText: String, imageName: String, description: String, document: String)
    {
        self.title = titled
        self.detailText = detailText
        self.description = description

        self.document = PDFDocument

        if let img = UIImage(named: imageName){
            image = img
        } else {
            image = UIImage(named: "default")!
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the code to recognize "document" as a PDFDocument but I get an error:Cannot assign value of type 'PDFDocument.Type' to type 'PDFDocument' where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the error is that you are attempting to assign a Type (`PDFDocument`) to `self.document` instead of the parameter that was passed to the `init` - `document`.  Also the type of the parameter must be a `PDFDocument`, not a `String`.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class State
{
    var title: String
    var detailText: String
    var description: String
    var image: UIImage

    var document: PDFDocument

    init(titled: String, detailText: String, imageName: String, description: String, document: PDFDocument)
    {
        self.title = titled
        self.detailText = detailText
        self.description = description

        self.document = document

        if let img = UIImage(named: imageName){
            image = img
        } else {
            image = UIImage(named: "default")!
        }
    }
}
```

Unless you *need* `State` to be a class for some other reason, I would suggest that make it a struct - This gives implicit immutability.  You can also simplify that `if` statement using a nil coalescing operator

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import PDFKit

struct State
{
    var title: String
    var detailText: String
    var description: String
    var image: UIImage
    var document: PDFDocument

    init(titled: String, detailText: String, imageName: String, description: String, document: PDFDocument)
    {
        self.title = titled
        self.detailText = detailText
        self.description = description

        self.document = document
        self.image = UIImage(named: imageName) ?? UIImage(named: "default")!
    }
}
```

Ok,

It seems that your actual question is "How do I get a `PDFDocument` from my application bundle?".

You can use something like this:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "SomePdfFile", ofType: "pdf") {
      do {
          let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
          if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url:fileURL) {
              // Do something with PDFDocument
          }
      } catch {
          print("There was an error - \(error)")
      }
}
```

You could turn this into a function:

```
func loadPDF(named: String) throws -> PDFDocument? {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "SomePdfFile", ofType: "pdf") else {
        return nil
   }

   let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
   return PDFDocument(url:fileURL)
}
```

Comment: I have implemented your Code above but get an error at the line self.document = PDFDocument error:Cannot assign value of type 'PDFDocument.Type' to type 'PDFDocument' Am I missing anything?

Comment: Sorry, that was a cut and paste error.  I have updated it

Comment: I changed to document as you explained but get a new error:Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'PDFDocument'.  I have been struggling with this for days.

Comment: You need to pass a `PDFDocument` that you [created from a URL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdocument/1436091-init), not a `String`.

Comment: I guess my last question is: Do I do this in this struct?  Here is what  my array looks like:var states = [State]()
        states.append(State(titled:"Alabama", detailText:"Reciprocal State", imageName:"usaFlag", description:"Agreement Exist", document:"Alabama.pdf"))

Comment: You could pass a string that represents the URL to the initialiser and try and retrieve and the PDF, but what if you can't retrieve it?  You might need to make the initialiser *failable* - I would probably retrieve the URL before creating the struct and only do so if you can get the PDF

Comment: I have added the PDFs in the project locally.  as in the Bundle.  As I guess I must have asked the wrong question as I am a newbie.  I have an array of titles, description and image that displays on a UITableView.  I wanted to add a PDF to the array.  I guess I am not sure what I am doing but thanks.  I guess I will read the guides more.  Thanks

Comment: your absolutely correct.  However this is what issue I have.  How would I view different PDFs instead of the one file.

Comment: Use a variable to hold the name of the file and pass that to `Bundle.main.path` instead of the simple, fixed, string I have shown there.